# how to enroll a user in all courses on Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have a Moodle with a SSO.

Users sign onto a site and click on a link to come to my Moodle.

When they arrive, I want to enroll them on every course on my Moodle.

However, I am unable to get the sql to work.

Here is what I have:

```
$ra = new object();
$ra->roleid = 5;
$ra->contextid = $contextid;
$ra->userid = $user->id;
$ra->hidden = 0;
$ra->enrol = 'manual';
//$ra->enrol = 'self';
/// Always round timestart downto 100 secs to help DBs to use their own caching algorithms
/// by repeating queries with the same exact parameters in a 100 secs time window
$ra->timestart = 0;
$ra->timeend = 0;
$ra->timemodified = time();
$ra->modifierid = 0;

// Enrol the User for the Course
$ra->id = $DB->insert_record('role_assignments',$ra);
```

Comment: Not enough information to go on. What error do you get? Can we see the whole block of code rather than just this section, so that we can see where $contextid is being set?

Comment: The problem is that I get no error.  I just thought that a Moodle user had experienced the same issue.

Comment: Have you get error reporting enabled to its highest level? If you post the full block of code I may be able to help, but with only that there's nothing I can suggest really.

Comment: please take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966238/moodle-user-enrollment-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966238/moodle-user-enrollment-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use auto enrol plugin for the purpose of enrolment. When the user clicks into course they get automatically enrolled to the courses by use of this plugin. Link: https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_auto

Answer (score 7):

To enroll a user, a following code snippet might be useful
It emulates manual enrollments in an automated way.

```
function enroll_user($userid, $course, $modifier) {                                                
    global $DB;                                                                                    
    $enrolData = $DB->get_record('enrol', array('enrol'=>'manual', 'courseid'=>$course));          
    $user_enrolment = new stdClass();                                                              
        $user_enrolment->enrolid = $enrolData->id;                                                 
        $user_enrolment->status = '0';                                                             
        $user_enrolment->userid = $userid;                                                         
        $user_enrolment->timestart = time();                                                       
        $user_enrolment->timeend =  '0';                                                           
        $user_enrolment->modifierid = $modifier;                                                   
        //Modifierid in this table is userid who enrolled this user manually
        $user_enrolment->timecreated = time();                                                     
        $user_enrolment->timemodified = time();                                                    
    $insertId = $DB->insert_record('user_enrolments', $user_enrolment);                            
    //addto log                                                                                    
    $context = $DB->get_record('context', array('contextlevel'=>50, 'instanceid'=>$course));          
    $role = new stdClass();                                                                        
        $role->roleid = 5;                                                                         
        $role->contextid = $context->id;                                                           
        $role->userid = $userid;                                                                   
        $role->component = '';                                                                     
        $role->itemid = 0;                                                                         
        $role->timemodified = time();                                                              
        $role->modifierid = $modifier;                                                             
    $insertId2 = $DB->insert_record('role_assignments', $role);                                    
    add_to_log($course, '', $modifierid, 'automated');                
    return array('user_enrolment'=>$insertId, 'role_assignment'=>$insertId2);                      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I automatically enroll students to courses. You just have to manipulate it a little bit to use it for all course ids. I hope this helps you.

```
// enroll student to course (roleid = 5 is student role)
function enroll_to_course($courseid, $userid, $roleid=5, $extendbase=3, $extendperiod=0)  {
    global $DB;

    $instance = $DB->get_record('enrol', array('courseid'=>$courseid, 'enrol'=>'manual'), '*', MUST_EXIST);
    $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id'=>$instance->courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);
    $today = time();
    $today = make_timestamp(date('Y', $today), date('m', $today), date('d', $today), 0, 0, 0);

    if(!$enrol_manual = enrol_get_plugin('manual')) { throw new coding_exception('Can not instantiate enrol_manual'); }
    switch($extendbase) {
        case 2:
            $timestart = $course->startdate;
            break;
        case 3:
        default:
            $timestart = $today;
            break;
    }  
    if ($extendperiod <= 0) { $timeend = 0; }   // extendperiod are seconds
    else { $timeend = $timestart + $extendperiod; }
    $enrolled = $enrol_manual->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $roleid, $timestart, $timeend);
    add_to_log($course->id, 'course', 'enrol', '../enrol/users.php?id='.$course->id, $course->id);

    return $enrolled;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would help, if you ask a question or describe your doubts in details and not just fill the free space in the comment section ;-)

Comment: if you are free i can explain my doubt..in this group..https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers